# django serving media files in production (comparing to PHP frameworks)

Tags: django

I'm a django newbie. I've read that all django projects, deployed in production environment, should serve media files (uploads) through web server such as apache. My question is - **why is that**?

There are lots of PHP frameworks - eg. symfony 1 and 2 - which don't follow the rule. Once you've made your app accessible through a web server, you don't have to change anything depending on the env you deploy. There is just the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` configured on the web server and somewhere inside this directory lies the upload directory - that's all. You can be sure that no one will access PHP, sql files and so on - thanks to the proper framework architecture and the document root. Why is it different in django?

edit: besides, preparing different code for different environments (e.g. [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#django.conf.urls.static.static)) is quite a bad approach, since you can't use exactly the same code to deploy a project in different envs (and the code from the link makes sense only for debug env.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because with PHP your code is served from web server's public directories together with static and media files. So when you request any of these static files web server serves them directly without  executing any PHP code along the way.

In Django your code is running separately and all requests are processed by python code in Django. This is inefficient to serve static files, it's more efficient to serve allow a web server like Apache or Nginx to serve them directly without going through any python code.

Comment: Did I get it right, that the PHP approach is less efficient than django/python approach because it work slower? One more question - "in django your code is running separately" - isn't the same as with PHP frameworks? When the web server gets a request, it executes a PHP script (which executes all framework stuff) and when the PHP script is over, it serves the response to the web server client. Where is the difference?

Comment: The difference is in the files location.

Comment: Your PHP files and your static files usually are all mixed somewhere in public_html / htdocs or whatever is your webserver DOCUMENT_ROOT. In djando though your files are usually independent of the webserver, django code can run somewhere else, it can even run by a linux user not related to the one that owns the webserver.

Comment: To connect django to your webserver you  most likely will have to attach a WSGI or a dynamic backend to your webserver (apache/nginx/lighthttpd) and if you don't specify for webserver to serve media and static directories of you django app separately then your django app will serve it which is  inefficient because you python request/response cycle will be executed for nothing when those static files are better to be served directly by the webserver.

Comment: PHP on the other hand doesn't have  this problem because your static files in DOCUMENT_ROOT are served directly anyway. So in this way PHP site is a bit easier to setup than Django, but Django has other advantages and deployment gets very easy once you get used to it.

Comment: thank you very much for your explanation. I got it like this: in PHP both code and static/media files are served in the same channel, because those files reside together with PHP code and because PHP's support in webservers like apache doesn't need anything like WSGI interface (but it has it's own apache handler - mod_php5).

Comment: In python/django, on the other hand, the code, the static/media files and the webserver can be all on different planets (though keeping django code along with static/media files is the default). Since webserver's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is elsewhere than django code, the wsgi interface has to provide the path for the application - to process django code. This makes first channel. And since the webserver cannot serve static/media files by default (paths are different), those can either be served by the wsgi/python code (1st channel, inefficient) or directly by the webserver (2nd channel, efficient).